# Appending arrays to matrix using Cupy

Tags: python, numpy, cupy

I am using cupy to create a matrix and an array. I simply want to delete the first row of the matrix, and then append the new array to the matrix horizontally. I plan on putting this into a loop where I will continuously deleting the first row in the matrix and appending new arrays to the bottom. But I keep getting the error: `ValueError: All arrays to concatenate must have the same ndim`. The shape of the matrix is (10, 100) and the array is (100,).

```
import cupy as cp

hori_avg = [0]*100
buffer_size = 10
width = 100 
a = cp.zeros((buffer_size, width))

new_frame = cp.ones(100)*3

a = a[1:, :]                        #delete first row
a = cp.stack((a,new_frame), axis=0) #append new row, but not working
```

I get the same issue with concatenate and append does not seem to exist for cupy.

Answer (score 0):

The `new_frame` array should have dimensions exactly the same as that of array `a` for it to be used in `cp.stack` function. In this case, you need to use `cp.concatenate` after changing the dimensions of `new_frame` to (1,100). The corrected script is given below:

```
import cupy as cp

hori_avg = [0]*100
buffer_size = 10
width = 100 
a = cp.zeros((buffer_size, width))

new_frame = cp.ones((1,100))*3

a = a[1:, :]                        #delete first row
a = cp.concatenate((a,new_frame), axis=0)
```

As mentioned in the [cupy.concatenate](https://docs.cupy.dev/en/stable/reference/generated/cupy.concatenate.html) documentation,

> "tup (sequence of arrays) – Arrays to be joined.
> All of these should have the same dimensionalities except the
> specified axis"

That's why I modified the line `new_frame` array's shape with `new_frame = cp.ones((1,100))*3`, for unspecified axis (axis=1) to have the same dimension (i.e; 100)

#### A bit more on this:

Unfortunately, the cupy documentation isn't well developed yet (as of November 2020) but we can look into the corresponding Numpy documentation in most cases.

The [numpy stack function](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.19.0/numpy/core/shape_base.py#L372), unlike the [concatenate function](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html), enforces the equality of dimensions between arrays to be stacked in all axes. Both `cupy.stack` and `numpy.stack` calls their corresponding `concatenate` functions internally to join the arrays.